# Windows 7 automatically logs out when logging in

Tags: windows-7, login

A Windows 7 HP x64 computer is set to automatically log in (no password), but once it starts logging in, it starts to load the desktop after the welcome screen, but before icons or background images are loaded, it goes to the Welcome screen saying 'Logging Off'. I can log in with Safe Mode, and I ran a couple different virus scans, with no detections. I also tried checking the userinit.exe file in System32 (as suggested by MANY users for Windows XP), but it's the same version as a working system. I also checked the registry under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` for the `SHELL` and `UserInit` values, but they look normal. I tried to disable all startup items (through MSCONFIG) to select Diagnostic boot, but then I get a blue screen about the video driver not loading. Any other ideas?

**EDIT** I created a new user, and it could log in no problems. I am thinking it's the NTUSER.DAT file. I just renamed it to NTUSER.DAT.old, then tried logging in as the problem user. I could log in, but as a TEMP profile. His profile folder is now `C:\Users\TEMP`, and his old folder is still accessible but in the wrong location.

**EDIT 2** I can't seem to turn off the TEMP profile, so I'm open to other suggestions. Copying the folders (i.e. Documents, Music, etc) does not work, as it creates an additional TEMP.000 then TEMP.001 folder each time the user logs in.

Comment: Does it do the auto-logout if you log in as a different user?  (If you hold shift while logging out it should offer you the log in prompt so you can log in as a different user)

Comment: It just brings me to the welcome screen, with the only user available. I am going to try to create a new user and see if it lets that user on

Comment: The Shift does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple: abandon ship.

His old profile is shot. Especially if it is as elusive of a problem as this, you have no idea what else is broken **even if** you manage to get logged in. Who knows how long it will be before you are troubleshooting Yet Another Profile Issue.

Use the new profile. Drag and drop his data files.  Some programs may have to be reinstalled (if they were installed to the current user, rather than *All Users*).

Comment: That's what I'm thinking right now :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the registry key related to the user as per below:

1. Restart the computer and login as a Local Admin or another domain user.
2. Rename: `C:\Users\%username%`
3. Export (just as a backup in case you need it) and then delete the following registry key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
   (Look through each Profile key under this reg key and view the `ProfileImagePath` value
   to find which key is related to which user).
4. Logout and login as the original user and it will create a new profile for them.

If you do not delete the registry key it will continually give a temporary profile 
to that user infinitely or until you rename their `C:\Users\%username%` folder back.

Comment: This seems like a dangerous solution that has a very simple fix otherwise.  I would not suggest this to even the most experienced users.

Comment: It's still a possibility though, @ramhound.  That would also fix it

Answer (score 0):

i got that problem too that is windows update problem
1) got o your controll panel then click adminstratore tools scroll dow to bottom there will be windows update turn it off and change automatic to disabled thenb login on and choose your user account