# Moved user profile location, now I can't add a user

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, user-profiles

While reinstalling Windows 7 on my new SSD, I decided to move my user profiles to one of my HDDs. I followed this guide:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124198-user-profiles-create-move-during-windows-7-installation.html

I ran into the slight hiccup of not being able to log into my account - the seemingly common issue of the User Profile Service failing, as described by M$ here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215.

I did some fiddling with the registry from recovery mode, I don't remember all of them, but under 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` I changed; `Default` to `E:\Default`, `ProfilesDirectory` to `E:\`,
`ProgramData` and `Public` to `E:\Public`.

Also, within my key in the `ProfileList` key, I changed my `ProfileImagePath` to `E:\Username1`, as well as some other changes I don't remember. Somehow I got my account to work just about fine.

However, I tried to add another account (I also changed their `ProfileImagePath` to `E:\Username2`), and they can't log in. As soon as they try to log in, they are logged out again.

I followed the suggestions here: [Windows 7 automatically logs out when logging in](https://superuser.com/questions/322487/windows-7-automatically-logs-out-when-logging-in), but even new profiles have the same issues.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a mess. You backed up the registry before you started, right?

Comment: Most of this was done during the install process and before first logon, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 things to try. I will list them in the order I would try them:

1. If you have a backup of the registry, restore it.
2. Are there any restore points? If so, try to restore to one of them and see what happens.
3. Re-install Windows. Probably not what you want to do, but it would fix your problem! :)

Comment: 1. Doesn't exist (This was all done during/directly after install) 2. Same 3. *sigh*

Comment: On the plus side, it's not like you have a lot of data that will be lost, right?

Comment: I guess so, just a lot of stuff to reinstall.